# Passing an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a simple game where you click a sprite which increments a hit counter. Once the game is over I want the score to be passed over the the main menu from where the game is started but can't get it to work. Here is my code for three different classes, I'm not sure what to put in the method.

**Game Activity-**

```
public void finish(){
          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
          returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE",gameView.getHitCount());
          setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
          super.finish();
        }
```

**Game View-**

```
public String getHitCount() {

        String Score = Integer.toString(hitCount);
        return Score;

                /*Intent returnIntent = null;
                String Result = returnIntent.getExtras().getString("GAME_SCORE");
                TextView GameScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGuessGame);
                GameScore.setText(Result);
                return Result;*/
        }
```

**Main Menu-**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                    int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                    tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));
                }
            }   
        }

    }
```

Comment: It has something to do with the Game View hitcount method as the other code was provided for me.

Comment: Current you setResult value "GAME_SCORE" type of string. But in main menu you get it as type Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your return type of getHitCount() method.

   public int getHitCount(){

   ```
           return hitCount;
           }
   ```
2. In onActivityResult :

   tvScore.setText(""+Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));

Comment: Thanks that worked, Because the code was already provided I thought I had to change it to a String first.

Answer (score 0):

Game score was string but is fetched as int in onActivityResult